# How to go through multiple states with Angular 4 animations?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am working with Angular 4 animations, and I wanted to know what is the best way to go from an initial state to a final state, through other ones.
If we take this as an example (https://angular.io/guide/animations) :

```
animations: [
  trigger('animationState', [
    state('stateOne', style({
      // some style
    })),
    state('stateTwo',   style({
      // some style
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

So the question is, if I add a third and fourth state and I toggle the active state from 'stateOne' to 'stateTwo', how to define the transition so it goes automatically through the other ones like this : **stateOne => stateThird => stateFourth => stateTwo**. Is there a way to **define** a transition to have this behaviour without any workarounds ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Angular's [`keyframes()`](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#keyframes). Als take a look at [Complex animation sequences](https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences).